# How does clang use SourceLocation to keep track of the filename, line and column info of an identifier?

Tags: c++, clang

The documentation of `clang::SourceLocation` ([link](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#the-sourcelocation-and-sourcemanager-classes)) just says it cleverly encodes the information in a 32 bit integer and `clang::SourceManager` can decode it, but never elaborates on how.

The codebase of `clang::SourceLocation` ([link](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html)) and `clang::SourceManager` ([link](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html)) is too complicated to navigate and I hope someone who has prior knowledge about this could give me a hint.